# How to avoid append when computing the intersection of two lists?

Tags: cython

I am writing a function to compute the intersection between two sorted arrays (which may contain duplicates). So if the input is [0,3,7,7,7,9, 12] and [2,7,7,8, 12] the output should be [7,7,12] for example.

Here is my code:

```
cimport cython

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def sorting(int[:] A, int[:] B):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i = 0
    cdef Py_ssize_t j = 0
    cdef int lenA = A.shape[0]
    cdef int lenB = B.shape[0]
    intersect = []
    while (i < lenA and j < lenB):
        if A[i] == B[j]:
            intersect.append(A[i])
            i += 1
            j += 1
        elif A[i] > B[j]:
            j += 1
        elif A[i] < B[j]:
            i += 1
    return intersect
```

As you will see, I use a list to store the answers and append to add the answers as they arrive.  I am happy to return a python or numpy array if that will speed things up.

> How can I avoid append to speed up the cython?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of thing you usually want to pre-allocate the array (it's basically free to shrink it later). In this case it can't be longer than the shortest of your input arrays, so that gives you a starting size:

```
cdef int[::1] intersect = np.array([A.shape[0] if A.shape[0]<B.shape[0] else B.shape[0]],dtype=np.int)
```

You then just keep a running total of how what index you're at on that array (say `k`), so `append` is replaced by:

```
intersect[k] = A[i]
k += 1
```

At the end you can either return the memoryview `intersect[:k]` or convert it to a numpy array with `np.asarray(intersect[:k])`.

---

As an aside: I'd remove the Cython directive `@cython.cdivision(True)` since you aren't doing any division. I believe you should be thinking about whether these directives are useful and if they apply to your code rather than blindly copying them in out of habit.

Comment: Thanks so much! Is [::1] equivalent to [:] here?

Comment: Yes but `[::1]` tells Cython that it's contiguous in memory, which should give a small speed improvement. We know this is true since we allocate the array. You can optionally use it on the input arrays too, but then if you do that then you won't be able to accept _all_ numpy arrays (i.e. it won't work on a `[:,0]` slice of a 2D array)

Comment: That's very interesting. I am a little confused about the overhead of creating a numpy array and then returning a memoryview.  Following your advice my current version is https://bpaste.net/show/2c76e777bf0d .  As the returning array has to be converted to a numpy array at some point  I suppose we can't avoid that overhead but is there any difference in using return intersect[:k]  and return np.asarray(intersect[:k]) ?

Comment: It shouldn't much difference. The memoryview is just a tool Cython uses to get quick access to things like a numpy array so no memory is copied when it is created (the memory is always owned by the numpy array). I believe `np.asarray` should be able to get the original array back out of the memoryview without copying. Which you choose to return really depends on what you want to work with afterwards